# How to obtain latest slipstreamed installation media for OS X?

Tags: install, upgrade, dmg

I'm looking for a way to obtain an updated installation media for OS X 10.6.x, currently 10.6.6

I am looking for a similar solution to the Windows slipstreamed installation media and preferably a solution to put the kit on a USB drive in order to improve the installation speed.

Is this possible, and if it is how it is possible to get such a media?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same Answer as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934918/how-do-i-add-mac-os-x-10-6-6-update-to-my-mac-os-x-10-6-3-dmg/4939625#4939625):

Basically you want to use the System Image Utility to create a bootable .dmg you can than put on a USB drive.
Have a look at [this post](http://www.lanrev.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=582&sid=04640062eb4dd6cab46ba00f765ad3d2), it covers this process in detail (you probably can leave out some steps); this should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official method to 'slipstream' updates into OS X installation media.

To install OS X from a USB drive you can make an image of your OS X DVD and then restore that image to your USB drive and boot from it.

You could then download and put on that drive the Combo update:
http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1349

Yes, you have to run them separately, but then you don't have to wait for slower i/o and download times.

Answer (score 0):

If your machines are all desktops the using [MacOS Server and Netboot](http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/features/client-management.html) might be what you want.

Otherwise if your machines are all similar you might be able to get away with

1) Disc Copy the original to the USB drive
2) Boot new machine off USB
3) Disk copy from USB.

but I would probably use @zevlag's solution